# Many typing forms for some Islamic terminologies

Tags: sharia, arabic, muslim-practices

I am bit confused about this. I've seen some people type some Islamic terminologies in English using different forms. **For example:**

- Salams or AA (shorten form of Assalamu Alaikum)
- insha allah, in sha allah, or inshaallah.
- walaikum salam as, ws, pr wassalam.

It could be that the person was busy with work or that person has typing difficulties which led to typing these in a different form. Is this permissible in Islam? To write a specific terminology in a different from than the one which majority muslims are used to it ?

I asked a local scholar and I was told its OK because in his heart, that person actually meant to type the correct word but instead, that person wrote it in a different form due to the urgency of replying immediately.

Answer (score 2):

"Salam" simply means peace and some Muslims even say just salam instead of Assallamu Alaikum. 
As long as the meaning does not change it is ok. In Shaa Allah should be written like this to avoid the meaning being changed.

[image]

Comment: I think this is bit problematic, because what i was told by a scholar is, as long as i am not meaning any bad or different its ok. in this case, by using insha allah or inshaallah i did not try to mean that "create allah". confusing situation. :-|

Comment: _Intention_ holds paramount above all. So if you do not intend any harm in writing it, then it is okay.

Comment: @ahamedhassan if it is by accident then its ok but if you do it on purpose it changes the meaning so it is best to avoid it.